# Is there a way to quick move items?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I tend to fill my inventory up with a lot of items that I want to move to my Cargo Hold. Is there a faster way to move my items to the Cargo Hold instead of dragging each item individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click them, which is slightly faster.  Sadly there is no way to do multi-select or a bulk move.